# Publishing a three band ArcGIS ImageService and encoding tiles with LERC

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, image-service

I'm trying to publish an ImageService for a three-band mosaic dataset and serve tiles using the LERC format. My workflow is as follows:

1. Create the mosaic dataset: right click on a file geodatabase --> New Mosaic Dataset --> Pixel Properties --> set Number of Bands to 3
2. Publish as image service: once created, right click on the mosaic dataset --> Share as Image Service --> Caching --> Select "Using tiles from a cache"
3. Specify tile format: After specifying that this dataset will be cached, the Advanced Settings menu appears below Cached. Within this menu, LERC is not available from the Tile Format dropdown

LERC is available if I follow the above, but with a 1 band mosaic dataset.

Is this option be available in 10.4? Or will it be in 10.5? I'm able to read three band images with LERC encoding using the Export Image endpoint on an ImageService, but need to be able to consume these as tiles as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to esri folks (as posted on [this Github issue](https://github.com/Esri/lerc/issues/22#issuecomment-220659273)), this feature is not currently available:

> @mappingvermont It's definitely something very nice and important to have. We're considering to support it in 10.5.